# Horizontal lines glitch when recording video with any program

Tags: linux, video, screen-recorder

When I record video with any program (Simple Screen Recorder, OBS) in the final file I have a kind of crumpled video. Horizontal lines overlapping each other. I've tried to change OBS encoder, KDE settings changed backend compositor to OpenGL 2, 3.1, XRender. Please tell me which elements work when recording and where something can break.

[A screenshoot of video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSVq4.png)

ffmpeg version n4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 11.1.0 (GCC)

5.14.10-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The captured file was great. The problems were with the software to watch it. (VLC)